# unable to install locate or mlocate

Tags: apt, locate

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Ruinning `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

shows:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

but if I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mlocate locate`
I get

```
Package locate is a virtual package provided by:
  locate:i386 4.4.2-4ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'mlocate' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'locate' has no installation candidate
```

Please help! I never realised how much I depend on the find command..

Cheers,
Paul

**Update to answer @braiam**

```
#apt-cache policy locate mlocate
locate:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Package pin: 4.4.2-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4.4.2-4ubuntu1 -10
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
mlocate:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Package pin: 0.23.1-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     0.23.1-1ubuntu2 -10
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages




#uname -a
Linux xxxx 3.0.20-xenU #1 SMP Wed May 15 04:27:08 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Second update to answer @braiam**

```
:~# dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
:~# cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch
amd64
i386
```

**Third update to answer @braiam**

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg    
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                   
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]               
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [342 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages          
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4,627 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages        
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [85.2 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages               
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2,439 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages         
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [360 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [708 kB]                                                                                                                                                 
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]                                                                                                                                         
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [88.9 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,635 B]                                                                                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                     
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [11.5 kB]                                                                                                                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                           
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [222 kB]                                                                                                                                             
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                                                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                                                                                                                                                     
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                                                                                                                                                       
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14.0 kB]                                                                                                                                          
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [729 kB]                                                                                                                                                  
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11.4 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [226 kB]                                                                                                                                              
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.2 kB]                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                                                                                                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                                                                                                                                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                                                                                                                                                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                                                                                                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                                                                                                                                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                                                                                                                                                         
Fetched 2,925 kB in 19s (150 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                            
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Have you used `sudo apt-get install mlocate:amd64`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation it turns out this has been disabled by the hosting company.

> By default mlocate is not installed, and disabled if it is installed
>   by default. The reason for this is due to the cron tasks and IO load
>   it puts on the servers which can impact other servers on the same
>   host. IO is the biggest cause for slow down on hosts which is why we
>   are fairly strict. We prefer to encourage people to use the find
>   command to find things eg find / -iname "*somename*"

When trying to figure this out the first place I turned to was google, I was unable to find anything useful on this problem.

I have added this as an answer so that hopefully people Googleing "unable to install locate" in the future can know to ask their hosting company first!

Answer (score 1):

Create the `/var/lib/dpkg/arch` file with the following text:

```
amd64
i386
```

Then do, `sudo apt-get update` and now you can start installing things again.

Comment: sorry no dice, after doing this I get same results.

Comment: done, I removed the old output